# docker image delete from private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

According to the documentation, I should be able to delete the docker image using its digest id, however, when I try to do so, I get back a unhelpful message in the body:

**$ curl -X DELETE "https:/private_reg_url.com/v2/test/consul-core/manifests/sha256:990e6b2955ar14d423478a9f8b0a2263e4315a77e9a738627859a3b4da2ddb11”**

*{"errors":[{"code":"UNKNOWN","message":"unknown error"}]}*

I've since uploaded a newer image using the same tag, so this particular image now has no tags pointing to it, but the digest is still valid and I still can't seem to delete it.

Any help with this issue or how I may go about deleting an image from the docker registry?

Comment: Why not to use `docker` command line tool?

Comment: Nikem, I didnt know the docker cli did that as well. I know 'docker rmi <image-id>' removes the image but no from the repo.

Comment: It removes it exactly repo, where else?

Comment: 'docker rmi  <image_id>' deletes images locally not from the remote registry.  Maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: Hm, seems you are right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What version of docker distribution are you using? (https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#deleting-an-image)

Comment: Maybe running garbage collection could help? (https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/c6f63e298ebb1dd0a2ce5ada0c0d39e248132634/docs/garbage-collection.md)

Comment: Have you tried specifying your repo url and then the image name? for example: docker rmi example.com/<image_name> or docker rmi example.com:<port_no>/<image_name>

Comment: Have you tried without `curl -X DELETE "https:/private_reg_url.com/v2/test/consul-core/manifests/990e6b2955ar14d423478a9f8b0a2263e4315a77e9a738627859a3b4da2ddb11"` (without the sha256:) ? or even better, `curl -X DELETE "https:/private_reg_url.com/v2/test/consul-core/manifests/sha256%3A990e6b2955ar14d423478a9f8b0a2263e4315a77e9a738627859a3b4da2ddb11"` (encoding of the :)